# How to print a pdf to a specific tray with no user interaction in java

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I'm trying to set up a service that runs at night to print a bunch of invoices and other documents automatically to a bunch of printers. As of right now I can print the documents fine, but I need to be able to specify a tray (one with our company letterhead and one with stock white paper) Everything i've tried so far hasn't worked at all, I specify the MediaTray attribute in the PrintRequestAttribute set but that doesn't seem to do anything. Anybody had any experience with something like this?

My current code I'm using for testing looks like this.

```
// Create a PDFFile from a File reference
File f = new File("C:\\File.pdf");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb); // Create PDF Print Page
PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

// Create Print Job
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
pjob.setJobName(f.getName());
Book book = new Book();
book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
pjob.setPageable(book);
// Send print job to default printer


PrintRequestAttributeSet aset=new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaTray.MIDDLE); //Used several of the tray options here
pjob.print(aset);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing with Attributes(Tray Control, Duplex, etc...) using javax.print library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328012/printing-with-attributestray-control-duplex-etc-using-javax-print-library)

Answer (score 2):

I use jasper report.  Here is the code.

```
public void runReport()
{
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    try
    {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:/temp/jtest.jrxml");     
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());      

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
        /* Create an array of PrintServices */ 
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null); 

        PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
        job.defaultPage(pf);
        int selectedService = 0; 


        String theUserPrinterName = "\\\\office1\\printer1";
        AttributeSet attrSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet(new PrinterName(theUserPrinterName, null)); 
        services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attrSet); 
        try {
            job.setPrintService(services[selectedService]); 
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER); 
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1)); 

        exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter(); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        /* We set the selected service and pass it as a paramenter */ 
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, services[selectedService]); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, services[selectedService].getAttributes()); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE); 
        exporter.exportReport(); 
    }
    catch (JRException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Caught exception!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE); 
        try {   
            exporter.exportReport();
        }
        catch (JRException e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you actually using to print the PDF? Sending a PDF directly to the printer only works if the printer directly support PDF. Otherwise you need to rasterize with a Java library. There is a blog article suggesting ways to print PDF from JAva at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

Comment: I'm using [PDF Renderer](http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/) to convert the PDF file into PS to send to the printer.