# Silent printer program

Tags: java

I’m writing a java print program using java. I want to send a pdf file to different trays in the printer and I need to control the page rage. I don’t like to have printdialogbox in ordered to a print. This program is a silent printer program so I have to run this print program automatically

```
PageFormat format = job.defaultPage();
format.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT); 
printRequestAttributeSet.add(printerTray);
printRequestAttributeSet.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
Paper paper = new Paper();
double margin = 36; // half inch
paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin*2, paper.getHeight()   - margin*2);
pf.setPaper(paper);`enter code here`

job.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(), pf);

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader();
PDDocument document = pdfReader.loadPdf(pdfPath);

job.setPageable(document);
int firstno;
int LastNo;

printRequestAttributeSet.add(new PageRanges(firstno, LastNo));

//job.printDialog(printRequestAttributeSet);

job.print();//
```

I face some issue when I'm running this code. I'm unable to set the `AttributeSet`, so it's not sending to the tray I want to send, it's sending automatically.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: its a new question. i face some issue while i'm running this code. i'm unable to set the AttributeSet. so its not sending the tray i want to send. its sending automatically

Comment: @vkmss1986 For questions on StackOverflow, please provide as many details as you can. This includes the expected behavior of your problem, a description of what happens instead and what you have tried so far to tackle the problem. If you see any errors or stacktraces, please post them as well. Without enough information, we can only guess what exactly your real issue is.

Comment: In your code, you don't set `firstNo`and `LastNo`. What happens if you intialize them to other values, like `firstNo = 1` and `LastNo = 2`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing with Attributes(Tray Control, Duplex, etc...) using javax.print library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328012/printing-with-attributestray-control-duplex-etc-using-javax-print-library)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be as simple as:

```
job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#print%28javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet%29).

Comment: i did that as well. when i send the print request its throwing an error saying zero contain.

Comment: there is no programmatic error in the program. I'll add the working code with printdialogbox.                                     printRequestAttributeSet.add(printerTray);
  printRequestAttributeSet.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader();
  PDDocument document = pdfReader.loadPdf(pdfPath);
  
  job.setPageable(document);
  int firstno = 0;
  int LastNo = 0;
  
  printRequestAttributeSet.add(new PageRanges(firstno, LastNo));  
  job.printDialog(printRequestAttributeSet);  
  job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);

Comment: I am a bit confused. You said, an error is thrown. Where do you see this error? On the printer? Or as a Java stacktrace? What is the exact message?

Comment: printer. its say receive file size is zero in the printer log. so its pop up some red lights.