# Print PDF duplex with Java on AS400

Tags: java, pdf, printing, ibm-midrange, duplex

I have a PDF document that is stored in the iSeries' IFS folder and want to print it using Java that is running in the iSeries' JVM. Just printing the PDF and sending it to the outqueue works perfectly fine but now I want to to print it in Duplex mode using

```
String outqueueName = "/QSYS.LIB/QUSRSYS.LIB/" + outqueue + ".OUTQ";
        OutputQueue outputQueue = new OutputQueue(as400, outqueueName);
        parms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_OUTPUT_QUEUE, outputQueue.getPath());
        parms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_HOLD, hold ? "*YES" : "*NO");
        parms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_SAVE, save ? "*YES" : "*NO");
        parms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_SPOOLFILE, "");            
        parms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_DUPLEX, "*YES");
```

But the print outs are still coming out as single sided. Any ideas what I am missing here? I have found this one from 2013.

[Printing with Attributes(Tray Control, Duplex, etc...) using javax.print library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328012/printing-with-attributestray-control-duplex-etc-using-javax-print-library)

I am wondering if that is still valid for 2017?

UPDATE 2019

So it does not seem to be possible to print Duplex straight from the iSeries. As a workaround I slave all my duplex print outs over a Windows VM and send all my PDFs to the Windows printers.

Comment: I assume the printer successfully prints duplex directly from the OS?  You might try asking in the [JT400](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityoverview?communityUuid=23fbfc12-4c77-41b2-8455-5021dc4a8bfb) forum.